# How to access the next element in for loop in current index/iteration?

Tags: python

I'm barely learning python and trying to write some code, but running in some issues trying to access the next element in the list.

Here is part of my code:

```
for word2 in vocab_list:
    index2 = 0
    for elem in sentence2:
        if (elem == word2 and nextElem == nextWord2)
            do something
        index2 += 1
```

The issue is in the `nextElem` and `nextWord2`, how do I access them given that I'm in the current  iteration?

Comment: So you want two nested iterations, one over `vocab_list`, one over `sentence`, with the ability to peek at the following item in both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access any member of the list if you iterate by index number of the array vice the actual element:

```
for i in range(len(vocab_list)-1):
    for j in range(len(sentence)-1):
        if(vocab_list[i]==sentence[j] and vocab_list[i+1]==sentence[j+1]):
            print "match"
```

Comment: this is good, but the problem is I need to access an element in my vocab_list, each line in my vocab_list is actually divided into 3 indices, so if I use "for i in range(len(vocab_list)-1)", how would I be able to change it in such a way that I can access each index of i?...because your code traverses the list using i as the integer index, and this stores the whole line in the list

Comment: No problem - that means that you are iterating over a multi-dimensional array. This syntax will read the individual elements of each line in vocab_list: vocab_list[i][0], vocab_list[i][1], or vocab_list[i][2].

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for this, this will also prevent you from the `IndexError`'s:

```
for word2, nextWord2 in zip(vocab_list, vocab_list[1:]):
    for elem, nextElem in zip(sentence2, sentence2[1:]):
        if (elem == word2 and nextElem == nextWord2)
           #Do something
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> lis = range(5)
>>> for item, next_item in zip(lis, lis[1:]):
...     print item, next_item
...     
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Note that `zip` returns a list, so if the input data to `zip` is huge then it's better to use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), as it returns an iterator. And instead of slicing get iterators using [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

In the demo you can see that in the loop `zip` stops at `item=3`, that's because `zip` short-circuits to the shortest iterable. If you want the output to be `4, some_default_value`, then use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), it allows you provide default values for missing items in the shorter iterables.

Comment: Though in this case don't you need to ensure an even length? I think there's an itertools function that might allow odds

Comment: @WayneWerner You mean `iterools.izip_longest`?

Answer (score 5):

Store the *previous* words instead:

```
prev2 = None
for word2 in vocab_list:
    prev = None
    for elem in sentence2:
        if prev == prev2 and elem == word2:
            # do something
        prev = elem
     prev2 = word2
```

It is much easier to look behind than to look ahead.

As for using indexes, you can always use the `enumerate()` function to add an index to a loop; you could look ahead in this case with:

for j, word2 in enumerate(vocab_list):
    for i, elem in enumerate(sentence2):
        if i + 1 < len(sentence2) and j + 1 < len(vocab_list):
            nextElem = sentence2[i + 1]
            nextWord2 = vocab_list[j + 1]

but tracking the previous element is just easier.

Comment: the thing is, I need to access the first elem in sentence2 "first", and the second elem in sentence2 "second", these are adjacent words in a list that I want to check if first elem comes before second elem in my vocab_list also

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who upgrade to python 3.10, such function was added to
[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)

```
import itertools

l = [1,2,3]
for x, y in itertools.pairwise(l):
    print(x, y)
# 1 2
# 2 3
```